# cannot import LSHForest using sklearn 0.24.1

Tags: scikit-learn

I had problem in importing the sklearn neighbors library (called "LSHForest").

the online example here did exactly the same I did when importing the LSHForest, but mine is not working :(

Not really sure what is possibility wrong.

I'm using sklearn 0.24.1

Answer (score 3):

`LSHForest` was dropped from sklearn in version 0.21.

[github Issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8996), [PR](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/9078), [some earlier discussion](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4917)